# PHP "or" syntax statement

Tags: php, logical-operators

Moving over to PHP from another language and still getting used to the syntax...

What's the proper way to write this statement? The manual on logical operators leaves something to be desired..

```
if($var !== '5283180' or '1234567')
```

Comment: @Mike, Your link to the manual says to use this: "$d = (true  or  foo());" -- it doesn't say to write the $var twice as in the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, comparison is by using `==` and the reverse is `!=`. But if you want to compare values along with its data type, then you can use `===` and the reverse is `!==`.

Please refer to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for more information.

You can use the following:

```
if($var!='5283180' ||  $var!='1234567')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if($var != '5283180' || $var != '1234567')
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `or` functions identically to the normal `||`, but has a lower binding precedence. As such, these two statements:

```
$foo = ($bar != 'baz') or 'qux';
$foo = ($bar != 'baz') || 'qux';
```

might appear to be otherwise identical, but the order of execution is actually quite 
different. For the `or` version, it's executed as:

```
($foo = ($bar != 'baz')) or 'qux';

- inequality test is performed
- result of the test is assigned to $foo
- result of the test is ORed with the string 'qux';
```

For the `||` version:

```
$foo = (($bar != 'baz') || 'qux');

- inquality test is performed
- result of test is ||'d with 'qux'
- result of the || is assigned to $foo.
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on the others, as the OP mentioned they are new to PHP, there is a couple things to be considered.

First off, the PHP `or` that you're looking for is the double line (`||`) and each item must be a statement on each side of the `||`.

```
if ( $var !== '5283180' || $var !== '1234567')
```

*addition*:

As mentioned in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

The `or` operator is the same as the `||` operator but takes a much lower precedence.
Such as the given example (from manual):

```
// The constant false is assigned to $f and then true is ignored 
//Acts like: (($f = false) or true) 
$f = false or true;
```

Now as mentioned, there is the general comparison (`==` or 'Equal') and the type comparison (`===` or 'Identical'), with both having the reverse (not). In the given example, the test will check that `$var` is not identical to the values.

From [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> $a !== $b | Not identical | TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type.

With this said, double check that this is what you're actually trying to accomplish. Most likely you're looking for `!=`.

Comment: false. PHP does support `or` directly, but it binds at a lower precedence than `||`.

Comment: @MarcB I added a little on the `or` operator. However, what the OP is looking for is more on the way his statement should be written (which you do not even cover in your answer)